# Unable to fetch HREF using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Unable to fetch the link from the `href` tag using beautiful soup.

I have provided the html structure below. 
Tried various extracting logic but the code is returning blank all the time
Please advise

```
<div class="review_list_pagination">
<p class="page_link review_next_page">
      <a href="/reviews/in/hotel/best-western-star-residency.html" 
           id="review_next_page_link">Next page </a>
 </p>
</div>
```

Tried

`link = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "page_link review_next_page"})`

`link = soup.find_all('p', attrs = {'class': 'page_link review_next_page'})`

Result:

```
[<p class="page_link review_next_page"><a href="/reviews/in/hotel/best-western-star-residency.html?page=2&amp;" id="review_next_page_link">Next page</a></p>, 
<p class="page_link review_next_page"> <a href="/reviews/in/hotel/best western-star-residency.html?page=2&amp;" id="review_next_page_link">Next page</a></p>]
```

But
`print(link[0].get('href'))`

Result: Blank

Expected: `/reviews/in/hotel/best-western-star-residency.html?page=2&amp;`

Comment: maybe page use JavaScript to add element - BS can't run JavaScript.

Comment: why do you get `<p>` if `href` is in `<a>` ?

Comment: You can get href because you're trying it on a p tag rather than on the a tag.

Comment: `find_all('a', {"id": "review_next_page_link"})[0].get("href")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
link = find('a', {"id": "review_next_page_link"})["href"]
```

What you are getting is a p tag from the soup. You can not get a property of the inner a tag from the p tag you are finding.

The line above will find the  tag with id =review_next_page_link, and you can simply get its href value.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of future generations (:D), you can also use either of these:

```
soup3.select('a[id="review_next_page_link"]')[0]['href']

  #or

soup3.select_one('a[id="review_next_page_link"]')['href']

  #or

soup3.select('#review_next_page_link')[0]['href']
```

... and I'm sure there are more ways to do this. They all output:

```
'/reviews/in/hotel/best-western-star-residency.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways to tackle this one, I landed on the below. Hope that helps.

```
link = soup.find("p",{"class":"page_link review_next_page"}).a['href']
```